# How to align pandas time series

Tags: pandas, time-series

Let's assume we have the following two time series `ts_1` and `ts_2`:

```
d = {'date': ['2018-01-01',
              '2018-01-02 12:00:00.000',
              '2018-01-02 13:00:00.000',
              '2018-01-03',
              '2018-01-04'],
        'value': [9, 11, 12, 11, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
ts_1 = pd.Series(df['value'].values, index=df['date']).resample('D').count()
greater10 = df[df['value']>10]
ts_2 = pd.Series(greater10['value'].values, index=greater10['date']).resample('D').count()
```

Obviously, both time series do not have the same start and end point (and, therefore, same length), what would be exactly what I need.

How can I align the start and end point the maximum of each? Missing values shall be filled with `0`.

Comment: What is expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with iloc if need seelct first and last value of timeseries:

```
df = pd.concat([ts_1.iloc[[0, -1]], 
                ts_2.iloc[[0, -1]]], axis=1, keys=('ts1','ts2')).fillna(0)
print (df)
            ts1  ts2
date                
2018-01-01  1.0  0.0
2018-01-02  0.0  2.0
2018-01-03  0.0  1.0
2018-01-04  1.0  0.0
```

If need only align timeseries:

```
df = pd.concat([ts_1, ts_2], axis=1, keys=('ts1','ts2')).fillna(0)
print (df)
            ts1  ts2
date                
2018-01-01    1  0.0
2018-01-02    2  2.0
2018-01-03    1  1.0
2018-01-04    1  0.0
```

Another solution is use [`Series.align`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.align.html):

```
s11, s12 = ts_1.align(ts_2, fill_value=0)
print (s11)
date
2018-01-01    1
2018-01-02    2
2018-01-03    1
2018-01-04    1
Freq: D, dtype: int64

print (s12)
date
2018-01-01    0.0
2018-01-02    2.0
2018-01-03    1.0
2018-01-04    0.0
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

---

```
s21, s22 = ts_2.align(ts_1, fill_value=0)
print (s21)
date
2018-01-01    0.0
2018-01-02    2.0
2018-01-03    1.0
2018-01-04    0.0
Freq: D, dtype: float6

print (s22)
date
2018-01-01    1
2018-01-02    2
2018-01-03    1
2018-01-04    1
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Comment: The `align` option is exactly I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html) you should be able to do

```
result = pd.concat([ts_1, ts_2], axis=1, join_axes=[ts_1.index])
```

Assuming you would like to keep the index in ts_1